# Passing type to a hook just like useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, zustand

I have a custom hook built with Zustand that can store multiple types of data, but I want to be able to pass the type I will be using just like with the useState hook

```
import { Profile } from "@/types";
import { create } from "zustand";

type ActionData = Product | Category | Profile | null;

type ActionDataStore = {
    actionData: ActionData;
    setActionData: (actionData: ActionData) => void;
};

export const useActionData = create<ActionDataStore>((set) => ({
    actionData: null,
    setActionData: (actionData) =>
        set((state) => {
            return { actionData };
        }),
}));
```

This is how it should look like when I use it inside a component:

```
const {actionData, setActionData} = useActionData<Profile>()
```

Typescript should give me an error whenever i try to set the action data to anything other than a profile now. And actionData should be of type Profile aswell

Comment: Can you give an example how you are planning to use that, it is not quite clear

Comment: Image I have a table with multiple products and each product has an "Edit product" button, when you click the edit button you set this actionData to the product and access it from the modal where you can see all its data and access its id so u can know which product to update in the backend

Answer (score 0):

To make the useActionData hook generic so that you can specify the type when using it in a component. You can achieve this by making the ActionDataStore and the useActionData hook generic. Try the code below:`enter code here`

```
import { create } from "zustand";
import { Profile, Product, Category } from "@/types";

type ActionData = Product | Category | Profile | null;

type ActionDataStore<T extends ActionData> = {
  actionData: T;
  setActionData: (actionData: T) => void;
};

export const useActionData = <T extends ActionData>(
  defaultData: T | null = null
) =>
  create<ActionDataStore<T>>((set) => ({
    actionData: defaultData,
    setActionData: (actionData) =>
      set((state) => {
        return { actionData };
      }),
  }));

// Below is the hook with Profile type
const { actionData, setActionData } = useActionData<Profile>();
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your help but i'm still getting ts errors, 
Type 'T | null' is not assignable to type 'T'.

  'T | null' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'ActionData'.

    Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'T'.

      'null' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'ActionData'.ts(2322)

useActionData.ts(7, 5): The expected type comes from property 'actionData' which is declared here on type 'ActionDataStore<T>'

Comment: Okay that sounds like a Typescript mis-match. Check the shape of your object where you define i and check the properties you have there.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by that